# Number of subsets of $\{0,1,2,...,9\}$ with symmetric difference $\leq 2$

Tags: combinatorics

There is a problem asking to prove that among any 100 subsets of $\{0, 2, 3, \dots , 9\}$ there will be two with cardinality of their symmetric difference less than or equal to two. It is proven by defining a metric on the space of subsets with cardinality of symmetric difference as distance: for every subset we have 11 subsets the distance to which is $\le2$; consequently, there are 100 spheres each containing 11 points — 1100 points in all. 1100 $\ge$ 1024, therefore, at least one pair of the spheres intersects, and the distance between their centres is, by the triangle inequality, $\le2$.

Thinking, about this problem, however, I came to a stronger conclusion. We can encode any subset as a 10-bit string with 1s for elements present in the subset. Then we can find subsets with required cardinality of symmetric difference by negating bits. For every subset we have 10 subsets with c.s.d. equal to 1 and $\binom{10}{2} = 45$ subsets with c.s.d. equal to 2. If we include the original subset in our sample all 55 subsets constructed in this manner will be lost. Consequently, we can extract no more than $\lfloor1024/56\rfloor = 18$ subsets with pairwise c.s.d. $\ge2$. Is this true?

Comment: What's a symmetric difference of a set?

Comment: @5xum, as defined here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference . I made a mistake: the bound is not on the symmetric difference itself, but on its cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are taking your spheres a bit on the large side. If you take, as you are doing, two disjoint spheres of radius $2$, then their centres will be at distance at least $5$.

In the original problem, they show that you can have at most
$$
\frac{1024}{11} \approx 93.10
$$
disjoint spheres of radius $1$ (centres at distance at least $3$). So if you have at least $94$ points, two of them will have distance ${}< 3$.

What you are proving is that if you have more than $18$ points, two of them will have distance ${}< 5$.

Comment: Thank you! I think that I see my error now.